# Check app tamper in Android with signature

Tags: android

I want to put tamper check code in my Android app I'm developing to prevent it from pirates.

I used this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (checkAppSignature(this) == true){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }

    }


    public static final String SIGNATUREE = "aqKTfwHKzuY52bukXMaRKgXPQyA=";

    public static boolean checkAppSignature(Context context) {

      try {

        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()

            .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(),

                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {

          byte[] signatureBytes = signature.toByteArray();

          MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");

          md.update(signature.toByteArray());

          final String currentSignature = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);

          //compare signatures

          if (SIGNATUREE.equals(currentSignature)){

              return false;
          }

      }

        } catch (Exception e) {

      }

      return true;
    }

}
```

I called checkAppSignature(this) on create to check the code if it matches. The code I used was:

```
Log.d("CODE", "SIGNATURE:" + currentSignature);
```

To get the code which I put it here:

```
Public static final String SIGNATUREE = "aqKTfwHKzuY52bukXMaRKgXPQyA=";
```

And the log shows same value but still, the toast pops up invalid every time.

Can anybody provide some fixes or provide good code for protection?

Comment: "i want to put tamper check code in my android app im developing to prevent it from pirates" -- it will take a pirate a few minutes to undo this work. Checking *another* app's signature can be worthwhile (e.g., to see if some third-party app that you communicate with was hacked).

Comment: could you help me with codes i will give proper credit im beginner still learning and creating :)

Answer (score 0):

When comparing SIGNATURE and currentSignature, use .trim():

```
SIGNATURE.equals(currentSignature.trim())
```